# Change responsive div display

Tags: css, responsive

At the moment, I have 3 simple block : a big black one, next to him a smaller pink one, and a green one under the pink.
What I want, when resizing, is the pink block and the green one are on the same line.
[image]

The pink and green blocks are wrapped in a div, but I can't go any further :s
Any help?

```html
<div id="BLACK" style="background:#000;width:400px; height:500px;display:inline-block"></div>
<div id="WRAPPER" style="display:inline-block;">
  <div id="PINK" style="background: #f0c; width:200px; height:250px; display:block"></div>
  <div id="GREEN " style="background: #0f0; width:200px; height:250px; display:block"></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle of actual code](https://jsfiddle.net/90pftg24/)

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `media queries` and set `float: left` on inner `div`'s [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/90pftg24/1/)

```css
@media(max-width: 620px) {
  div div {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="chart_div1" style="background:#000;width:400px; height:500px;display:inline-block"></div>
<div style="display:inline-block;">
  <div style="background: #f0c; width:200px; height:250px; display:block"></div>
  <div style="background: #0f0; width:200px; height:250px; display:block"></div>
</div>
```

You can also use `display: flex` on `#wrapper` but you need to use `!important` to overwrite inline styles.

```css
@media(max-width: 620px) {
    #WRAPPER {
      display: flex !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="chart_div1" style="background:#000;width:400px; height:500px;display:inline-block"></div>
<div id="WRAPPER" style="display:inline-block;">
  <div style="background: #f0c; width:200px; height:250px;"></div>
  <div style="background: #0f0; width:200px; height:250px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will go for the display-flex solution.
I though I could do this without media queries

Answer (score 1):

Media queries are used when handling responsiveness of HTML structure. They are used to apply different css on different screen sizes. You can learn more about it from [http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp].

you can add this css for handling it in smaller screens:

```
<style>
    @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 980px){
      #WRAPPER { display: block !important;  }
      .smaller { display: inline-block !important; }
    }
</style>
```

apply `smaller` class to both div with id GREEN and PINK.
And use class if same css is been applied to different elements

your code will be now:

```
    <div id="BLACK" style="background:#000;width:400px; height:500px;display:inline-block"></div>
            <div id="WRAPPER" style="display:inline-block;">
            <div class="smaller" id ="PINK" style="background: #f0c; width:200px; height:250px; display:block"></div>
            <div class="smaller" id="GREEN "style="background: #0f0; width:200px; height:250px; display:block"></div>
        </div>

<style>
        @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 980px){
          #WRAPPER { display: block !important;  }
          .smaller { display: inline-block !important; }
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: I already tried this, but the problem is the wrapper was not next to the black block on larger screen. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yeah i overlooked the responsive part :/
still...since you don't want to use media quries...
I will suggest you to use bootstrap grid view 

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Its one of the most reliable and mature library and very simple to use.